# Como registrar um usuário padrão no início da aplicação?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

Em uma aplicação ASP.Net MVC preciso ter um registro de usuário padrão e para isso estou pensando em adicioná-lo na inicialização da aplicação.

No arquivo `Global.asax` fiz o seguinte:

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        // Registradores ...

        // Comando para setar os registros básicos
        App_Start.DatabaseConfig.SetDataDefault(); 
    }
}
```

E na classe `DataBaseConfig` eu tenho:

```
public static void SetDataDefault()
{
    using (var ctx = new Data.Context.ApplicationDbContext())
    {
        // Outras adições simples ...

        if (!ctx.Users.Any())
        {
            // Adiciona o usuário padrão
            ... // Oo heim.. !!??
        }
    }
}
```

Como proceder para adicionar um usuário nesse momento, julgando que preciso obter uma instância de `ApplicationUserManager` para registrar o usuário?

Answer (score 2):

Na verdade, é até bem simples, só estava faltando um pouco mais de pesquisa.

A questão era apenas saber instânciar a classe `ApplicationUserManager`, e não é complicado, era só acompanhar os parâmetros pedidos.

Enfim, com isso eu pude registrar o usuário:

```
if (!ctx.Users.Any())
{
    using(var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore<Model.User>(ctx)))
    {
        manager.Create(new Model.User
        {
            EmailConfirmed = true,
            UserName = "nome de usuário",
            Email = "login@provedor.com.br"
        }, "AQUI VAI A SENHA");

        ctx.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Sendo que `ApplicationUserManager` já é uma classe criada pelo template do Visual Studio com a opção *Individual User Account* selecionada.

Ela está declarada assim:

```
public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<Model.User>
{
    ....
}
```

Logo, eu poderia ter instânciado uma classe do tipo *UserManager* assim:

```
var manager = new UserManager<Model.User>(new UserStore<Model.User>(ctx));
```